# Formula tag in Hibernate Mapping class SQL queries

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

What are the valid SQL queries i can run on hibernate hbm formula tag
I want to execute select Now()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you mean with hbm formula tag, but maybe you are looking the list of avaliable query functions fo Hibernate. Check this out:

[Expressions](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions)